# How to pass variable from controller to javascript that is not inside a view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I want to pas this data to a javascript function that is in a javascript file :

```
    $data = $this->model_member->fetchMemberData();
```

The javascript function takes as a parameter  the `id_member` that's inside the `$data` variable.It is called on button click from a view, but if I pass the data to the view I'll have to load it and I don't want that since it is already loaded. How can I pass this data directly to the js function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways -

**1** - You can use php tags in your js code. So you can access the variable like this -

```
var id_member = "<?php echo $data['id_member'] ?>";
```

**2** - Store that $data in one hidden variable and than access it using any selector. For ex -

```
<input type="hidden" class="id_member_hidden">

var id = $(".id_member_hidden:hidden").val();
```

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.